Laravel Socialiteprovider problem: Driver [apple] not supported
I'm trying to get external authentication to work on my Laravel 10 website.
I've installed Laravel Socialite and got the built-in Google sign-in method to work without too much effort.
In order to get Apple sign-in to work, I've installed the Apple Socialite provider (https://socialiteproviders.com/Apple/) and followed all the configuration instructions, but when my controller tries to handle the Socialite redirect:
return Socialite::driver('apple')->redirect();

...I get the error:
Driver [apple] not supported.

Here's the in addition to the basic Socialite setup, here's the Apple-specific configuration I've done so far:

Added an apple section to config/services.php and added client_id, client_secret, and redirect to it
Added 'SocialiteProviders\Manager\ServiceProvider::class' to Providers array in config/app.php
Added this to the $listen array in app/Providers/EventServiceProvider.php:

\SocialiteProviders\Manager\SocialiteWasCalled::class => [
    \SocialiteProviders\Apple\AppleExtendSocialite::class.'@handle',
],

I've run php artisan config:cache and route:cache multiple times.
I know this is a simple mistake - anyone see this before and figured it out? Found some older similar posts but they didn't work for me.
Thanks!!

Does it answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45555003/driver-provider-not-supported-laravel-socialite

Thanks Mahidi, I saw that and tried everything there already but it didn't help.

Is this happening on your local environment? Are you sure you are clear of cached config? I don't remember if you have php artisan about on Laravel 10, also php artisan optimize:clear, make sure you did not run php artisan event:cache, else nothing you add to the event provider will be used

@matiaslauriti Yep that was it - event caching was on, and artisan event:clear fixed things up. Thanks!
